# The icon external viewer in the latex (the red book) does not work

Tags: latex, acrobat, pdflatex

The problem is that when I press the icon external viewer **(the red book icon)** to see the created pdf file in the systems' default pdf viewer (adobe acrobat reader), this icon does not work!

I use a texmaker editor in my windows 7 (64) computer.
Everything seems fine in my Texmaker, I can compile the tex file and see the pdf embed to my file. The pdf file is also created. 
I have checked options --> configure texmaker --> pdfviwer and "built-in viewer" and "embed" both have been selected.

I guess something is wrong with adobe acrobat setting or maybe there is a need to install something extra. This problem did not exist a while ago!!

Thank in advance for your suggestions.

This is the red icon that I am talking about:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happened to me as well. Matter got complicated since the whole area of the Pdf Viewer Settings was minimized inside `Configure Textmaker` -> `Commands` (I know this wasn't part of question but maybe someone else has this problem) so I didn't find them. They are in the lower right corner. This problem is solved by expanding the window by clicking on the corner with the mouse and pulling it out.

Now to the real question: did you change the path for the External Viewer below the External Viewer option? This has to be done even if the option isn't selected, since this is the same viewer you go to every time you press the `red-book icon`, even if embedded viewing is your first choice.

So click the little icon after the path field and find your Acrobat Reader and click `Open`. For example mine is at `C:/Program Files (x86)/Adobe/Acrobat Reader DC/Reader/AcroRd32.exe`so the whole text in that little field is: `"C:/Program Files (x86)/Adobe/Acrobat Reader DC/Reader/AcroRd32.exe" %.pdf`
Sometimes the folder Program Files (x86) can be called Programs or similar.

Comment: Thank you Mianen, 
You are right the path for the External Viewer should be written correctly even if the option was not selected. now, it is working.